# How do I extend a Google OAuth token obtained on client side at server side

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I have a web application that has frontend built on EmberJS and backend in Java.

I'm making the user sign in using Google OAuth and requesting the scope: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar`

```
{
  "El": "google_user_id",
  "Zi": {
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "access_token": "access_token",
    "scope": "openid email profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
    "login_hint": "login_hint",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "id_token": "..AF16AF6oc7Fl2uv5V9r",
    "session_state": {
      "extraQueryParams": {
        "authuser": "0"
      }
    },
    "first_issued_at": 1550770587899,
    "expires_at": 1550774187899,
    "idpId": "google"
  },
  "w3": {
    "Eea": "google_user_id",
    "ig": "Shivang Tripathi",
    "ofa": "Shivang",
    "wea": "Tripathi",
    "Paa": "https://mnsbfsdbf/photo.jpg",
    "U3": "shivang.tripathi@org.com"
  }
}
```

Now, I send this response to the server.
The server can use the provided "access_token" to do various tasks like get calendars list, etc by making API calls using REST.
Eg. Making a call to https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList with "access_token" as Authorization Header.

I'm running into a problem though..
The token is short lived and expires in 60 minutes.

Can I somehow extend this token to never ending token or long lived token?
Facebook allows this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/refreshing
Can someone tell me if Google allows this from server side and how?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there's no way.

I had to take another route, which is:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer

1. Generate a auth url and redirect the user to it:
   https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive.metadata.readonly&access_type=offline&include_granted_scopes=true&state=state_parameter_passthrough_value&redirect_uri=http://localhost:5000/callback&response_type=code&client_id=
2. Handle the callback, it has the authorization_code
3. Use that code to get a refresh token and access token:
4. POST /oauth2/v4/token HTTP/1.1

   Host: www.googleapis.com
   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

   code=4/P7q7W91a-oMsCeLvIaQm6bTrgtp7&
   client_id=your_client_id&
   client_secret=your_client_secret&
   redirect_uri=https://oauth2.example.com/code&
   grant_type=authorization_code

Answer (score 0):

It's not true to say "there is no other way". The correct way is to make the auth request again, but add "prompt=none". btw "login_prompt" should be an email address or a Google user id.